# Canonical tag for content split across multiple pages

Tags: seo, canonical-link

We have pages which have been split into multiple pages as they are too in depth. The structure currently...

```
Page (www.domain.com/page)
```

We have split this up like so...

```
Page + Subtitle (www.new-domain.com/page-subtitle-1)
Page + Subtitle (www.new-domain.com/page-subtitle-2)
Page + Subtitle (www.new-domain.com/page-subtitle-3)
```

I need to know the correct way of adding in multiple canonical tags on the original page. Is it search engine friendly to add say 3/4 canonical tags linking to 3/4 separate pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is what you should do -

1. Keep the complete page even if you are dividing into component pages.
2. Use rel="next" and rel="prev" links to indicate the relationship between component URLs. This markup provides a strong hint to Google that you would like it to treat these pages as a logical sequence, thus consolidating their linking properties and usually sending searchers to the first page.
3. In each of the component pages, add a rel="canonical" link to the original (all content) page. This will tell google about the all content page.

This strategy is recommended by [google - read here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1663744?hl=en).

Answer (score 0):

Canonical tags are basically to **consolidate link signals for duplicate or similar content.** With that said, you are not supposed to have multiple canonical tags in a page. You have two options.

1. If your old page is going to go away, then you should pick one primary page(in the split pages) and do a 301 redirect, so the SEO value are carried over to that new primary URL.
2. If its going to stay, you can create internal links to the new pages. But make sure the content is different, so that it does not count as duplicate pages.

Hope this helps.